# Getting the value of a gridview column in rowcommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

this is what i have tried but i m getting null for job_Name

```
 GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);

 int RowIndex = row.RowIndex; // this find the index of row

 string job_Name = row.Cells[1].Text;
```

`job_Name` is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
private void RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    var grid = sender as GridView;
    if (grid == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    var  index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    var row = grid.Rows[index];
    string job_Name = row.Cells[1].Text;
}
```

Comment: I m getting error '' Input string was not in a correct format.'' on    var index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

Comment: iCommandName="ApplicantShortList" and  i have used it not Rowcommand

Comment: @WajidAliKhan - is is asp.net Webforms or MVC? please add the HTML site to your question and more details if you can

Comment: it is asp.net page

Comment: @WajidAliKhan - Please the aspx designer (HTML) to your question